# updated cxf library 3.1.1 to 3.1.5

Tags: java, apache, web-services, rest, cxf

I have updated cxf library from 3.1.1 to 3.1.5 and my rest service which is returning rest response earlier is not returning a rest response now after the update.

```
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/myService")
public Response createUpdate() {

    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity("Update saved successfully.").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

When i am using cxf 3.1.1 library the response is -

```
*{
    "value": "Update saved successfully."
}*
```

when i updated to cxf 3.1.5 the response is -
    *Update saved successfully.*

It was not even a json response.

Let me know, how can i fix this issue.

Comment: which client you are using?

Comment: I am using firefox rest client for executing the service.